# Verify Shopify Webhooks

Tags: node.js, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app

I am trying to setup shopify webhooks for my app and I want to verify the webhooks. I am creating the webhooks using [this api](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/webhook#post-webhooks). I am trying to verify the webhooks in Node Js and this is the code that I am using to do it.

```
const verifyWebhook = async (req, res, next) => {
  const hmac = req.get("X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256");
  const body = await getRawBody(req);

  // Create hash based on body and key
  const generatedHash = crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", secretKey)
    .update(body)
    .digest("base64");

  // Compare our hash to Shopify's hash
  if (generatedHash !== hmac) {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }

  req.body = JSON.parse(body);
  next();
};
```

However, I am not so sure about the secret that I should use. I tried using the api secret available on the credentials tab for an app but it doesn't seem to work.

However, when I tried creating the webhooks from the store settings and used the secret available there then it works fine but I am not sure about the secret I should be using in case of webhooks created using the api. I have read the documentation and it mentions some shared secret but I am not able to figure out what it is.

Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: you find the same into app setup section to partner account.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find it in partner settings could you please help me out? If you are talking about the client secret available in app overview section, then I have tried it and it doesn't seem to work.